# Synchronising transactions between two different services using producer and consumer approach

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, producer-consumer

I want to create a distributed application using consumer and producer architecture.

So, I have basically two different services, one of them will hold the Order request and another will deal with Payments[image]

My question is: can one service be a Consumer and Producer at the same time?

To give more context about the consumer and producer flow:

1 - Order Service Publishes a message to the order-queue
2 - Payment Service will consume this message and then will do their internal payment stuff, having some result, we are going to write the and Publish a new message to another queue (order-status queue)
3 - Order Service will also consume the order-status queue, and check the message and update the order internally in his Database

Sorry for the long text, but i want to explore more scenarios working with queues and distributed systems

Answer (score 2):

> can one service be a Consumer and Producer at the same time?

Yes.

However you should not use the same connection to the MQ server for both consuming and publishing. Have your service establish two connections.

This will help you deal more easily with a few potential headaches, in general it'll prevent consumer and publisher from interfering with each other. For example:

- disconnections: if one of the two connections drops, it won't affect the other
- TCP backpressure: if the publisher is too fast, the MQ server may apply backpressure, then the consumer may not be able to send ACKs.

You can find this and more interesting advice [here](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/part1-rabbitmq-best-practice.html).